# How to broadcast a music file using rtsp

Tags: mp3, broadcast, rtsp

How can I broadcast an mp3 file using rtsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source VideoLAN project [will do RTSP](http://wiki.videolan.org/RTSP).